# I want to resize my mount point partition of ubuntu 12.04 and install winndows 7 .HOw can I do that?

Tags: boot, partitioning, filesystem, mountpoint

I want to resize the Ubuntu 12.04 partition and install Windows 7. How can I do that?

Please refer to the screenshot of Gparted editor. I want to resize the dev/sda3 partition.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot is not loaded...

Yet, I assume you need to have both Windows and Linux OS's.

Your hard drive can have 4 partitions: 2 will go for Windows and 1-2 for Linux (your choice).

So, just make empty space, for example 50GB, before /dev/sda3 by formatting and deleting partitions /dev/sda1-2.

Run Windows installation and choose that empty space (Windows will automatically create 2 partitions: 100MB and (50GB-100MB)).

Worth mentioning that Windows will overwrite bootloader and you will not be able to access Linux. To overcome this issue make a LiveCD with Linux and reinstall Grub (or whatever loads your OS).

At the end, you will have a Grub loader which will prompt your with both Linux and Windows OS's.